# How do I extract a column of comma-separated values (each value is a hyperlink) into a single array?

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-slides

I have a spreadsheet with a column containing links to images (These are inputted by users in a form). There can be multiple images which means that the links will show up as comma-separated values in each row.

I want to extract each of these links individually and perform an action(paste the contents into a new slide in google script - which I already have a working function for).

(For example, if I have a row with entries [Link A, Link B, Link C] and the second row with entries [Link D, Link E], I want to first iterate on row 1, read Link A, and extract that image, read Link B, extract that image, read Link C extract that image, sense that the row is over, jump to the next row and do the same till all rows are read)

I am however unable to read the links one by one. I did the logical (read the rows one by one) and use the `split` method to read the values between each comma one by one, but it still does not give me the answer.

Here is my code:

```
function collateImages(){
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
 //var targetDocument = SlidesApp.create("Output File"); // Target file for the collation 
 var targetDocument = SlidesApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1VajsMSozYtDdIRY7cJfc8GuU0Gr5TmV438cTnf9VgtU/edit?usp=sharing"); // Target File 
 var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange(); // Range of the entire database

 var finalArray = []; // creates an empty array to log each of the URLs one-by-one
  
 for (var i = 1; i < dataRange.getLastRow(); i++){    // Iterate by each row 
  for (var j = 0; j < dataRange.getValues()[i][2].split(",").length; j++){
    finalArray.push(dataRange.getValues()[i][2].split("'")[j]);
    //Logger.log(dataRange.getValues()[i][2].split(",").length);
    //addImageToSlide(dataRange.getValues()[i][2],i,targetDocument);
  }
 }
  
  
}


// Function to get file id from url
function getIdFromUrl(url) { return url.match(/[-\w]{25,}/); }

//Add Image with URl "ImageUrl" on slide number "index on a presentation named "deck"  
function addImageToSlide(imageUrl, index,deck) {
  var slide = deck.appendSlide(SlidesApp.PredefinedLayout.BLANK);
  var imagefile = DriveApp.getFileById(getIdFromUrl(imageUrl));
  var imageblob = imagefile.getBlob();
  var image = slide.insertImage(imageblob,0,0,500,400);
  var slide = deck.appendSlide(SlidesApp.PredefinedLayout.BLANK);

 }
```

Comment: I think that when you provide the sample input and output you expect, it will help users think of your current issue and the solution.

Comment: You have a typo - it should be `finalArray.push(dataRange.getValues()[i][2].split(",")[j]);` and not `finalArray.push(dataRange.getValues()[i][2].split("'")[j]);`

Comment: Got it - silly error. Works now. Thanks.